# How to make a template function const if the template is true

Tags: templates, constants, d

I have a class method with a bool template-parameter (is_const) which only calls a mutable function when is_const is false (using static if).  How can I tell the D compiler to make this function const for is_const = true but not for is_const=false?
I don't want to have to copy-paste the function, but I can't see any other way to do it. (I can't use inout because it does indeed behave differently for is_const=false and is_const=true)

Comment: I think duplicating the function body is the only way to do it. static if and mixin both work only on the whole decalaration - they can't selectively add just one little change to the signature. I'm not posting this as an answer yet since I'm not quite sure, but almost sure, no hacks I've tried so far have gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a const overload that forwards to the de facto const implementation:

```
class C
{
    void m(bool is_const)() // de-facto const when is_const is true
    {
        static if(!is_const) {/* ... mutate ... */};
    }
    void m(bool is_const)() const if(is_const)
    {
        return (cast() this).m!true();
    }
}
```

You then have to be extra careful not to mutate when `is_const` is set.

Comment: Yeah, this is better than what I was attempting (make the entire function body a string mixin).  Except in the spirit of safety, I'll do it the other way around and make the mutable one call the immutable one.  Then I'll explicitly cast "this" wherever a mutable function is called within m (so that if all such casts are wrapped with static if(!is_const), it's easy to verify by eyeball that the function is const-correct)

Comment: Casting away const and mutating is undefined behaviour, though.

Comment: Does that mean this solution doesn't work and I should go back to the mixin approach?